# How to convert array to string array?

Tags: ruby

Here i have ruby code like this for converting arrays to string array and also observed that difference between puts and print/p both or giving different output

```
a= ["ruby"]
print a.to_s
```

output:

```
"[\"ruby\"]"
```

But  need like this when i use print/p and class should be string

```
"["ruby"]"  or '["ruby"]'
```

Comment: Sounds like you’re doing some serialization. Why do you need such string? Maybe there’s a better way to solve it.

Comment: i need that string array for evaluation in one of my ruby code

Comment: @Bharath : What is a _string array_?

Comment: its nothing but array is in string format. I think you have to look at @sumak answer which is provided below

Comment: @Bharath how do you evaluate the string in your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you accept having single quotes instead of double quotes:

```rb
array = ['ruby', 'is', 'cool']

"['#{array.join("', '")}']"
# => "['ruby', 'is', 'cool']"


# You can then define you own method:
def puts_array(array)
  puts "['#{array.join("', '")}']"
end

# Or overwrite Array#to_s method
class Array
  def to_s
    "['#{self.join("', '")}']"
  end
end

puts_array(array)
# => "['ruby', 'is', 'cool']"
puts array.to_s
# => "['ruby', 'is', 'cool']"
```

Comment: I need one more help how the same thing do it for hash `{"make" => "tata", "year" => "2006"}`  Expected output `"{"make" => "tata", "year" => "2006"}"`

Comment: open a new question and we'll answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"'#{['ruby','othersElements'].join("', '")}'"
```

Where "," is the element separator

```
.join("', '")
```

Comment: i am getting like this `'ruby', 'othersElements'` but in your case i should get like this `"['ruby', 'othersElements']"`

Answer (score 0):

You just need `to_s`. Its output is compatible with `eval` (as long as elements can be serialized with `to_s` themselves):

```
string = ["a", "b", "c"].to_s
=> "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"

rebuilt = eval string
=> ["a", "b", "c"]

rebuilt.class
=> Array

rebuilt[0].class
=> String
```